# Why no menu bar in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

When you move your cursor to the top of the screen in Libreoffice you don't get a menu.  You do for other applications like Firefox and Thunderbird but not for Libreoffice.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

> sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk

It will remove the global menu bar and replace it with a basic one, but it might give you functionality. That worked for me anyways.

You can also try getting updates - there may have been a bug fix for it:

> sudo apt-get update

Or just use the GUI updater.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu software center -> search for "lo-menubar" and install. Now you have a unity menu for Libre Office. Make it so.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with LibreOffice 3.6.2.2 and this is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk
```

Then opened LibreOffice and there was the menu, no need to install `lo-menubar`.

Answer (score 1):

Just updated Ubuntu. Latest updates included several LibreOffice updates. This appears to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've been updating my ubuntu 12.10 and this problem still occurred.

Here is what I've done and it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-gtk
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

(I know this is an old question but happened to me again now)

For me, changing the Java Runtime fixed the problem, instead of using the Oracle one I choose the Ubuntu and the bar appears again.

[image: Choosing Ubuntu runtime instead of Oracle]