# Menubar in libreoffice (Ubuntu 17.10 gnome)

Tags: gnome, 17.10, libreoffice

I have recently switched to Ubuntu gnome and I can no longer see the global menu bar of several programs, libreoffice apps included, as shown below.

[image]

How can I show the global menu bar in the libreoffice applications? For example, in Fireforx, I can display it by pressing `Alt`. However, I tried pressing `Alt`as well as the F keys and I cannot get the menu bar displayed.

I have found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219491/why-no-menu-bar-in-libreoffice), however, I am not really fond on removing `libreoffice-gtk` as I can still have the menu bar when launching Ubuntu on Unity.

I have also read about installing `lo-menubar`, yet I cannot find instructions for installing it (I have found [this website](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/+source/lo-menubar) though)

I is intriguing that I can have the menu bar (ribbon option) on libreoffice writer (below). Yet I cannot enable it on libreoffice draw because I am missing the menubar (in case the draw application supports the ribbon layout, like writer)

[image]

Comment: yes, please check edited question

Comment: What's the gap between the title-bar and the icons (red box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdq1w.png). Can you click there?

Comment: That's indeed a good question. I tried to click on it (both right and left click) and nothing happens. Please have a look at my edits, it appears that the gap you've mentioned is occupied by the menu bar (ribbon option) on libreoffice writer.

Comment: You’re actually talking about enabling a local menu in the top bar so it isn’t hidden by the global menus. I don’t have 17.10 so I’m not sure if this applies but check system settings, appearance, behavior tab, and under “show the menus for a window,” enable the “in the window’s title bar” option.

Comment: @Emily It doesn't apply to 17.10 as it came with GNOME instead of Unity.

Comment: @pomsky yes it is indeed odd. I could do that, the thing is that I think it is not only libreoffice related, as some other apps are not displaying the menu bar, while others are, as shown [in this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009076/global-menu-bar-in-ubuntu-gnome-17-10).

Comment: Hmm... did you install this extension and now disabled it: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/?

Comment: @pomsky indeed I have installed it a while ago. I have just read the reviews and it seems this extension messes up with gnome. Any way to completely remove it from my system, something like purging?

Comment: Ah OK. @pomsky, do you think it could be something that could be fixed in dconf? I actually use gnome-panel in Unity and noticed that the top panel in gnome-panel, which has a global menu bar, sometimes sticks itself on top of my application window menus so I had looked into issues related to gnome-panel a bit and saw some fixes that suggested changing some settings in dconf.

Comment: @Emily In this particular scenario, that specific extension makes changes to some gsettings/dconf keys which are not reverted once the extension is disabled/removed. See my answer to the other question by OP: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009076/global-menu-bar-in-ubuntu-gnome-17-10 Probably that was the root of OP's problem (unfortunately they can't apply the fix in my answer due to broken gsettings/dconf).

Comment: @pomsky Thanks for the clarification! That is unfortunte :-/. If gsettings/dconf are broken, is the only fix a reinstall?

Comment: @Emily You can try the answers from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins